# WP8 loading listbox locations on map

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, windows-phone-8, gps

I'm new to wp8 application development I would like to know how to load the map locations with  listbox places.. I have no idea on it so please help me to know how to do it.. thanks in advance..

I have a `listbox` with the places loaded with its latitude and longitude and a `MAP` button a side.. when I click the `MAP` button I should display the listbox places into the map.. so please anyone help me to do this...

This is a code to just add map to the page.. (code behind)

```
private void Map_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            Map MyMap = new Map();
            MyMap.Height = 392;
            MyMap.Width = 412;
            MyMap.Center = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(-25.235,133.611);

            MyMap.ZoomLevel = 2;
            MyMap.LandmarksEnabled = true;
            MyMap.PedestrianFeaturesEnabled = true;
            MyMap.ColorMode = MapColorMode.Dark;
            srch.Children.Add(MyMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know how your listbox looks like so I just created a empty Pushpin for each location.

Following Method loops through every row in your ListBox and calls the method to draw the pushpin

```
private void ReadListBox()
{
    foreach (var location in YourListBox)
    {
        DrawLocationToMap(new GeoCoordinate(latitudeInListBox, longitudeInListBox));
    }
}
```

Following method creates the location pushpin and adds it to your map

```
private void DrawLocationToMap(GeoCoordinate currGeo)
{
    Pushpin locationPushPin = new Pushpin();
    locationPushPin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    MapOverlay locationPushPinOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    locationPushPinOverlay.Content = locationPushPin;
    locationPushPinOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    locationPushPinOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(currGeo.Latitude, currGeo.Longitude);

    MapLayer locationLayer = new MapLayer();
    locationLayer.Add(locationPushPinOverlay);

    MyMap.Layers.Add(locationLayer);
}
```

You'll need the [WPToolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to use PushPins.
To install the toolkit you'll need [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/). How to install: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget

After NuGet is installed, open the console
[image]

and enter

> Install-Package WPtoolkit

Finally just add the namespace into your xaml

> ```
> xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
> ```

Comment: Where is the latitude and longitude? How do you fill it?

Comment: Ahh sorry you'll need the WPToolkit: http://phone.codeplex.com/
Just add it with NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/wptoolkit

Comment: sure thanx.. can u plz help me to how to do it..?

Comment: Install NuGet: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget
Install WPToolkit: http://abload.de/img/2013-11-2311_29_30-w6cyc.png and enter "Install-Package WPtoolkit"

Comment: i checked ur edit.. mai knw about trafficlayer.Add() i'm getting error over ther..

Comment: `trafficLayer` should be `locationLayer`